# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'circular'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

On IE9 and IE8 with debug activated I get the following error message:

> SCRIPT438, Object doesn't support property or method 'circular' aboutus, line 587 character 1

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.blahblahblah.com/en_US/js/jquery.tools.min.4.6.8-b3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
// $(document).ready(function() {

$("#chained").scrollable({hoverClass: 'hover'}).circular().autoscroll({
    steps: 1,
    interval: 3000      
});
$("div.items").click(function() {
 window.location="/blahblahblah/customers";
});
// });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards, 
seeker7805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"circular" is a property of the scrollable method rather its own method. Your function call should look more like this:

```
    $("#chained").scrollable({hoverClass: 'hover', circular:true}).autoscroll({
        steps: 1,
        interval: 3000      
    });
```